# How to fetch data by id from parent's sibling element in JasperReports report items list (xml datasource)

Tags: xml, xpath, jasper-reports

I want to create a list of order items; for each item, I want to display an "Item ID" and "Address Line" field; the data of the former field comes from a child element on the item, but the data from the latter must be fetched from a sibling of the item's parent using an unique id that is referenced in the item.

I've created a simplified xml data source and report in in order to illustrate the problem. The xml data is defined as follows:

```
<data>
<productorder>
    <item>
        <id>10001</id>
        <installationAddressId>1</installationAddressId>
    </item>
    <item>
        <id>10002</id>
        <installationAddressId>3</installationAddressId>
    </item>
</productorder>
<address>
    <id>1</id>
    <addressLine>Street 1, 12345 Berlin Germany</addressLine>
</address>
<address>
    <id>2</id>
    <addressLine>Street 2, 12345 Berlin Germany</addressLine>
</address>
<address>
    <id>3</id>
    <addressLine>Street 3, 12345 Berlin Germany</addressLine>
</address>
</data>
```

The simple (incorrect) report is:

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="SimpleOrderItemReport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="0d316a3a-9d1c-4483-bf7d-d1bd9165e0cb">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="SimpleOrderItemReportDataAdapter"/>
<subDataset name="OrderItemList" uuid="c1a7dc7b-2bc3-4f1f-bab9-ae6e3b207739">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="SimpleOrderItemReportDataAdapter"/>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/data/productorder/item]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="id_1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[id]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="installationAddressId_1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[installationAddressId]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="addressLine" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[../../address/addressLine]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
</subDataset>
<queryString language="xPath">
    <![CDATA[/data]]>
</queryString>
<detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
        <componentElement>
            <reportElement x="124" y="19" width="390" height="30" uuid="84a1e8b2-13df-4391-9cdd-39a9d4d79434"/>
            <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="OrderItemList" uuid="0d232993-a132-45ff-813c-d00d8a685d9e">
                    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/data/productorder/item")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:listContents height="30" width="390">
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="40" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="2b9a8530-32e3-4ecb-8dc4-3d8d9d30b191"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField>
                        <reportElement x="190" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="d570993d-201b-4a43-9147-73036dd0cf11"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{addressLine}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="40" height="30" uuid="b96b0be3-fa58-42f1-8270-004a08a7c3df"/>
                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <text><![CDATA[Item ID:]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="90" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="f85e298c-e3e0-42e3-bd0d-fc7c7808c2f1"/>
                        <textElement verticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        <text><![CDATA[Address Line:]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                </jr:listContents>
            </jr:list>
        </componentElement>
    </band>
</detail>
</jasperReport>
```

For the xml data that was provided above, I want to see the following two rows in the report:

1. Item ID: 10001   Address Line: Street 1, 12345 Berlin Germany
2. Item ID: 10002   Address Line: Street 3, 12345 Berlin Germany

I can't seem to find a field description or xpath query that would achieve this goal. Does anyone know how to do get my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use JasperReports with Xalan as XPath executer (and that's the default configuration, see [net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.executer.factory](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.executer.factory)), you can use the XSLT `current` function to refer to the current node.

In your case, the field should look like this:

```
<field name="addressLine" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[../../address[id = current()/installationAddressId]/addressLine]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

Comment: Thank you, dada! Your description is exactly what I was looking for!